# Viewing source query/code of the plugin "Check Geometries" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geometry

[image]I am running a plugin "Check Geometries" to determine the topology errors. It's running smoothly. But I want to have a SQL or Python query out of the executed process. For all other tools like Union, Clip or Dissolve we can have a query after running the tools. But I am not getting it for the "Check Geometries" tool.

Is there any way to get it? Because I want to run this query in another environment, not in QGIS only.

Comment: Are you talking about this tool https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgischeckvalidity or this plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeometryValidator/ ?

Comment: Its Check Geometries tool